# Adjective or noun in "the former"

Tags: meaning, adjectives

Is the dictionary wrong? Here's an example; you decide (use the rules of grammar and common human natural-language sense, not the rules of logic, which rely entirely on antecedent definitions):

> The United States, England and Canada have a lot in common. The
>   **former**, for example, used to own the other two!

*Former* here seems to me to be a noun. But according to m-w.com and wiktionary.org, this can't be true because it is just an adjective! How can this be?

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/former: noun --
**the former**: the first or first mentioned of two: distinguished from *latter*

Comment: Incidentally I think your example is wrong- The US did not ever own England.  Also your question in the *PS/EDIT* section leads me to believe that you have your definitions reversed.  -Remember the "*latter*" comes later in the list. *Former* is "BeFORe" the latter.

Comment: the former is england in that case.

Comment: @David I think most people would read your example and assume that *former* referred to the US, not to England (as Jim and I both did). Though not authoritative, [this](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1286572) wordreference.com thread also seems to agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Former](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/former_2)* can indeed be used as a noun. Dictionaries are not wrong, just incomplete.

Comment: And some are less complete than others.

Answer (score 6):

The OED points out that [*former*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/73471), although normally an adjective,  can also be used absolutely or elliptically — and even inflected as a noun!

> The former’s phlegm was a check upon the latter’s vivacity.

Sure smells awfully nouny to me.  I’d say your dictionary is wrong.

Comment: merriam webster has no such entry

Comment: @David Not sure what point you might be making.

Comment: @tchrist Perhaps that a standard American reference doen't use it as a noun (in this sense), whereas a standard British reference does? But as you say, not all dictionaries are complete.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I hardly consider the OED a British-national thing.  It’s an English-language thing, and always has been.  For some uninformed Americans to ignore it is just their own bad luck, and easily remedied. Pretending that MW and the OED serve the same purpose just for different countries requires serious dissembling. The OED was ***the*** standard reference we used  at the last *American* university I was associated with; some people know quality scholarship irrespective of its purported pondian orientation.